# Rails Joins through a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I'm trying to do a pretty simple join in my model to list all 'Locations' in a 'Post' with a certain id.

Currently, each post `has_many :locations, :through => :location_post`. I'm using the 'blogit' gem, which puts posts in a module named 'Blogit::Posts'.

I'm getting a `wrong argument type Class (expected Module)` error when I try to run the following in my Post.rb model:

```
module Blogit
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_save :reuse_existing_locations

def reuse_existing_locations
  existing_locations = Location.include(Blogit::Post).first
end
```

How can I do a join through a module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish so just some notes and observations:

- By looking at the [code](https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit/blob/6b8ffe/app/models/blogit/post.rb), it's clear that `Blogit::Post` is a class, not a module.
- The `include` method takes modules (not classes), that's the error you're seeing.
- You are calling the `include` method on the `Location` model and that seems kind
  of strange to me. Did you mean to call `includes`? But then again that
  wouldn't make much sense since it seems like you've got a `many to many`
  relationship between `Location` and `Blogit::Post`.
- In the `Location` model (which doesn't need to be in the `Blogit` namespace), you can simply reference the `Blogit::Post` model as
  follows:

  ```
  has_many :posts, class_name: "Blogit::Post", ...
  ```
- If `existing_locations` is in fact an attribute on the model and you want to assign to it, you need to put `self` in front of it (as in `self.existing_locations`). Otherwise you're just creating a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to use ActiveModels `includes` instead of Rubys `include`, which is to include methods from another module.